# Adobe Target Experience not consistent cross devices

Tags: adobe

When running an adobe target experiment I am finding that the experience is not consistent for a user cross devices.

I am using JMeter to run a test to simulate a user making requests from multiple devices. I am doing the following steps using http requests:

1. Generate Marketing Id on device 1 - dpm.demdex.net/id?d_visid_ver=2.5.0&d_fieldgroup=MC&d_rtbd=json&d_ver=2&d_orgid=XXXXXXXXXXX%40AdobeOrg&d_nsid=0
2. Sync Marketing id with a unique user id (XID) - (org).demdex.net/id?d_mid=${MID}&d_orgid=XXXXXXXXXXX&d_cid=XXXXX%01${XID}%011&dcs_region=8
3. Send signal to AAM qualifying user for segment required for experiment (AU Retail) - (org).demdex.net/event?d_rtbd=json&d_jsonv=1&d_dst=1&c_orgregion=au&c_industrytype=retail&d_cid=XXXXXX%01${XID}
4. Get Content From Target (POST Request) - (client).tt.omtrdc.net/rest/v1/mbox/${__UUID}?client=(client) Body =

   {
    "mbox" : "DEVOB00001A",

   "mboxParameters" : {
      "mboxMCGLH": 8,
      "vst.(org)_onboarding.authState" : 1,
      "vst.(org)_onboarding.id": "${XID}",
      "vst.(org)_onboarding.thirdPartyId" : "${XID}"
   },
    "requestLocation" : {
      "host" : "www.(org).com"
    }
   }

The above gives me an experience (Either experience a or b)

[image: Experience setup]

But when I do the following 100 times I am getting a mix of experience A and B:

1. Generate new Marketing Id on a new device
2. Sync Marketing id with a unique user id (XID) from above
3. Get Content From Target

Since this is the same user accessing from multiple devices I would expect that the experience should be the same every time. My understanding is that a user should be put into an experience once then remain in that experience regardless of which device they use.

Am I doing something wrong or is this expected functionality?